# Can chrome apps access to the specific page's DOM

Tags: google-chrome-app

I connect to device via serial port for read some data from it. I need to send this data to specific web page's DOM.

We already tried communication with content_scripts but it cannot work. I develope packaged application and content_scripts is not working in packaged application.

Comment: Chrome apps can't access browser tabs. You'll need to create an additional [extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) and control it by [sending messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external). Alternatively, if you're the author of that web site you can make it communicate with your app [directly](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm. I solved problem with your suggestion.